# kubernetes setup on ubuntu machine with 2 minion and 1 master node

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am following this tutorial at https://gettech1.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/setting-up-kubernetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/ to setup kubernet multi node with 2 minions and 1 master node on remote ubuntu machines, after following all the steps it goes OK. But when I am trying to run the ./kube-up.sh bash file. It returns the following errors

> ubuntu@ip-XXX-YYY-ZZZ-AAA:~/kubernetes/cluster
>
> $ ./kube-up.sh
>
> Starting cluster in us-central1-b using provider gce ... calling
>
> verify-prereqs Can't find gcloud in PATH, please fix and retry. The
>
> Google Cloud  SDK can be downloaded from
> https://cloud.google.com/sdk/.

**Edit :** I have fixed above issue after exporting different environment variables like

```
$ export KUBE_VERSION=2.2.1
$ export FLANNEL_VERSION=0.5.5
$ export ETCD_VERSION=1.1.8
```

but after that it is generating this issue

> kubernet gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar:  Child returned status 1
> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: There is no kubernetes version 2.2.1. Also, you might want to check kubeadm for an easier setup solution on non-cloud based hosts

Answer (score 1):

The command you should be executing is `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh`

Without setting that environment variable kube-up.sh tries to deploy VMs on Google Compute Engine and to do so it needs the gcloud binary that you don't have installed.

Comment: I have ran that command to setup the environment variable and then ran that command `./kube-up.sh` then it show that error. Actually I am a new comer on this things of Kubernet. One more thing I am using my .pem file for the step 6 not any .pub as described.

Comment: If you just ran `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu` and thereafter `kube-up.sh` then you haven't exported that variable and the script can't see it. Either run the command exactly as it is or do `export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu` before `kube-up.sh`

Comment: Ok, I am going to try it again & give you feedback again. One more thing I have read that `Master node needs to be connected to the Internet as it download the necessary files`. what is the meaning of it ? may I need to ssh on master node while running the commands ?

Comment: when running the command `KUBERNETS_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh`  its showing `... Starting cluster using provider: ubuntu
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling verify-kube-binaries
!!! kubectl appears to be broken or missing
!!! Cannot find kubernetes-salt.tar.gz` and when running `KUBERNETS_PROVIDER=ubuntu` & `./kube-up.sh` individually its shows `.. Starting cluster in us-central1-b using provider gce
... calling verify-prereqs
Can't find gcloud in PATH, please fix and retry. The Google Cloud 
SDK can be downloaded from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/.
`